# C++ : Shift register, SNRZI encoder/decoder

Tags: c++, shift

### EDIT: solved, thx to Dialecticus, the correct code is in the second "frame" (?).

i have to write a program which will encode and decode large bit streams from/to files. The coding is Scrambled Non Return to Zero Invert, which is being used in the serial video data transmission. First i had to try out the functionality of my algorithm on some short and simple bit streams, e.g. a preamble 3FF 000 000 (10 bit words) which represents 10 ones and 20 zeros when written binary.

Here is the scrambler drawing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef3XP.gif

I wrote a test console program just like on the drawing which should encode this preamble and then decode the answer to get the starting preamble bit stream. This doesn't work, i.e. the decoder doesn't return the preamble. Here is it (i hope it is readable):

The code like Dysaster suggests:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
// Encoder -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cout<< endl <<" Encoder "<< endl;

// create an input vector and initialize it with 3FF 000 000
bool bInput[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
vector< bool > vbInput( bInput, bInput + sizeof( bInput ) / sizeof( bool ) );

// create the shift register
bool bShiftReg[10] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

// create an output vector 
vector< bool > vbOutput(40);

// iterator for the input
vector<bool>::iterator itInput = vbInput.begin();
cout<<"\n Input: ";
for( itInput = vbInput.begin(); itInput < vbInput.end(); itInput++)
    cout << " " << *itInput;

cout<<endl<<endl;

// iterator for the output
vector<bool>::iterator itOutput = vbOutput.begin();

for( itInput = vbInput.begin(); itInput < vbInput.end(); itInput++)
{
    // handle first and last values separately
    bShiftReg[ 9 ] = bShiftReg[ 9 ] ^ bShiftReg[ 8 ];
    bShiftReg[ 0 ] = *itInput ^ ( bShiftReg[ 4 ] ^ bShiftReg[ 8 ] );

    bool bTempReg[2];
    bTempReg[0] = bShiftReg[0];
    bTempReg[1] = bShiftReg[9];

    // shift operation
    for( unsigned char ucIndex = 8; ucIndex > 0; ucIndex-- )
    {
        bShiftReg[ ucIndex ] = bShiftReg[ ucIndex - 1 ];
    }

    bShiftReg[0] = bTempReg[0];
    bShiftReg[9] = bTempReg[1];

    // write to output
    //*itOutput = static_cast< int > ( bShiftReg[ 9 ] );
    *itOutput = bShiftReg[ 9 ];

    cout<<"\n Schift Reg: ";
    for( int i=0;i<10;i++)
    { cout << " " << bShiftReg[i]; }

    cout<<" Output: " << *itOutput;

    itOutput++;
}
cout<<"\n Output: ";
for( itOutput = vbOutput.begin(); itOutput < vbOutput.end(); itOutput++)
    cout << " " << *itOutput;

cout<<endl<<endl;

// Decoder -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cout<< endl <<" Decoder "<< endl;

// load the old ouput to the new input but use only bits 10:40
itOutput = vbOutput.begin() + 10;
for( itInput = vbInput.begin(); itInput < vbInput.end() - 10; itInput++)
{
    *itInput = *itOutput;
    itOutput++;

}

cout<<"\n Input: ";
for( itInput = vbInput.begin(); itInput < vbInput.end(); itInput++)
    cout << " " << *itInput;

// reset the shift reg
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++) bShiftReg[i] = 1;

// set output iterator to the begin of the vector
itOutput = vbOutput.begin();

for( itInput = vbInput.begin(); itInput < vbInput.end(); itInput++)
{
    // shift operation
    for( unsigned char ucIndex = 9; ucIndex > 1; ucIndex-- )
    {
        bShiftReg[ ucIndex ] = bShiftReg[ ucIndex - 1 ];
    }

    // write to output
    *itOutput = ( ( *itInput ^ bShiftReg[0] ) ^ bShiftReg[5] ) ^ bShiftReg[9];

    // write the first and second values
    bShiftReg[ 1 ] = bShiftReg[ 0 ] ^ *itInput;
    bShiftReg[ 0 ] = *itInput;

    cout<<"\n Schift Reg: ";
    for( int i=0;i<10;i++)
    { cout << " " << bShiftReg[i]; }

    cout<<" Output: " << *itOutput;

    itOutput++;
}
cout<<"\n Output: ";
for( itOutput = vbOutput.begin(); itOutput < vbOutput.end(); itOutput++)
    cout << " " << *itOutput;

cout<<endl<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

### console output:

Encoder

Input:  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Output:  0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

Decoder

Input:  0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Output:  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0

------------------- end console output

the code like Dialecticus suggests:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
// Encoder -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cout<< endl <<" Encoder "<< endl;

// create an input vector
bool bInput[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
//bool bInput[] = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 };
vector< bool > vbInput( bInput, bInput + sizeof( bInput ) / sizeof( bool ) );

// create the shift register
//bool bShiftReg[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
bool bShiftReg[10] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

// create an output vector 
vector< bool > vbOutput(40);

// iterator for the input
vector<bool>::iterator itInput = vbInput.begin();
cout<<"\n Input: ";
for( itInput = vbInput.begin(); itInput < vbInput.end(); itInput++)
    cout << " " << *itInput;

cout<<endl<<endl;

// iterator for the output
vector<bool>::iterator itOutput = vbOutput.begin();

for( itInput = vbInput.begin(); itInput < vbInput.end(); itInput++)
{
    // calculate values of every flipflop and the output and save them in a temp array
    bool bTempReg[10];
    bTempReg[0] = *itInput ^ ( bShiftReg[ 4 ] ^ bShiftReg[ 8 ] );
    bTempReg[1] = bShiftReg[0];
    bTempReg[2] = bShiftReg[1];
    bTempReg[3] = bShiftReg[2];
    bTempReg[4] = bShiftReg[3];
    bTempReg[5] = bShiftReg[4];
    bTempReg[6] = bShiftReg[5];
    bTempReg[7] = bShiftReg[6];
    bTempReg[8] = bShiftReg[7];
    bTempReg[9] = bShiftReg[8] ^ bShiftReg[9];
    *itOutput = bShiftReg[ 9 ];

    // assign values of the temp array to the flipflops
    for( unsigned char ucIndex = 0; ucIndex < 10; ucIndex++ )
    {
        bShiftReg[ ucIndex ] = bTempReg[ ucIndex ];
    }

    /*cout<<"\n Schift Reg: ";
    for( int i=0;i<10;i++)
    { cout << " " << bShiftReg[i]; }

    cout<<" Output: " << *itOutput;*/

    itOutput++;
}
cout<<"\n Output: ";
for( itOutput = vbOutput.begin(); itOutput < vbOutput.end(); itOutput++)
    cout << " " << *itOutput;

cout<<endl<<endl;

// Decoder -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cout<< endl <<" Decoder "<< endl;

// load the old ouput to the new input 
vbInput = vbOutput;

cout<<"\n Input: ";
for( itInput = vbInput.begin(); itInput < vbInput.end(); itInput++)
    cout << " " << *itInput;

// reset the shift reg
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++) bShiftReg[i] = 1;

// set output iterator to the begin of the vector
itOutput = vbOutput.begin();

for( itInput = vbInput.begin(); itInput < vbInput.end(); itInput++)
{
    // calculate values of every flipflop and the output and save them in a temp array
    bool bTempReg[10];
    bTempReg[0] = *itInput;
    bTempReg[1] = bShiftReg[ 0 ] ^ *itInput;
    bTempReg[2] = bShiftReg[1];
    bTempReg[3] = bShiftReg[2];
    bTempReg[4] = bShiftReg[3];
    bTempReg[5] = bShiftReg[4];
    bTempReg[6] = bShiftReg[5];
    bTempReg[7] = bShiftReg[6];
    bTempReg[8] = bShiftReg[7];
    bTempReg[9] = bShiftReg[8];
    *itOutput = ( ( *itInput ^ bShiftReg[0] ) ^ bShiftReg[5] ) ^ bShiftReg[9];

    // assign values of the temp array to the flipflops
    for( unsigned char ucIndex = 0; ucIndex < 10; ucIndex++ )
    {
        bShiftReg[ ucIndex ] = bTempReg[ ucIndex ];
    }

    /*cout<<"\n Schift Reg: ";
    for( int i=0;i<10;i++)
    { cout << " " << bShiftReg[i]; }
    cout<<" Output: " << *itOutput;*/

    itOutput++;
}
cout<<"\n Output: ";
for( itOutput = vbOutput.begin(); itOutput < vbOutput.end(); itOutput++)
    cout << " " << *itOutput;

cout<<endl<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

console output:

Encoder

Input:  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Output:  1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1

Decoder

Input:  1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0  0 0 1 1
 Output:  0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

im not sure about the order of shifting and writing to the output but it doesn't work either way. i really do appreciate your help, thank you!

EDIT: new version of code and console output. now the output of the descrambler looks similar to the input of the scrambler but it's rotated and there are 8 ones instead of 10. it doesn't matter if i make the output vector longer, e.g. to 40 bits.

Comment: My first idea on how to debug this is to do it on paper and compare the result with the one given by program. It's tedious job, so I'll delegate it to you. Let us know about the progress...

Comment: the question is why am i not getting the source preamble after encoding and decoding =). or why it isnt working. i will try to execute this on paper.

Comment: New version gives good result. You just need to disregard first 10 bits of decoder output (as Dysaster pointed out), because they are part of the initialization, and will be identical for any input, as long as initialization is the same (all ones in your case). What counts is what comes after them. And after every given input you need to feed the (de)scrambler with additional 10 bits, so that input bits don't get lost in the registers. I suppose that last 10 zeroes are just for this purpose, and that real test input is only 10 ones and 10 zeroes.

Comment: alright i added additional 10 bits to the input of the scrambler and fed the descrambler with scrambler's bits 10:40 and 10 zeros (see main post) but unfortunately with no success.

Comment: Don't omit first 10 bits from decoder input. They are important. Ignore first 10 bits from decoder *output*.

Comment: aww i tried it yesterday but for testing i changed the bits 30-40... now i changed some other input bits and it looks like it works! Thanks pal, i owe you one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Okay, I found one possible bug. While decoding you calculate output after you shifted all registers, but while encoding you calculate output before the shifting. Which one is it?</strike> No, I got it wrong, second try:

EDIT: Imagine that output is just another register. I think that you need to calculate the value of output as your first operation within each loop. After that, calculate the value of all registers. After that assign those values to registers. Don't assign values before you calculated them all.

The bottom line: first calculate all values, and only then assign all values. In general case that implies using temporary variables. You can get away from using temps only if there are no loops.

The solution: introduce another set of registers (bTempReg), have 11 lines of code where you assign a value to each bTempReg[0..9] and to output, and then in mini-loop[0..9] assign values of bTempReg back to bShiftReg.

Comment: You mean in the source code or in the drawing? actually i calculate the output after shifting in decoding and encoding. i tried to do it before but it didnt work as well.

Comment: I mean in the code. Look the code again. In encoding you assign value to `*itOutput` before the mini-for loop, and in decoding you assign it after the loop. I can't wrap my head around which one is correct way, but it has to be the same for both encoding and decoding.

Comment: yes but the mini for loop contains just a cout console output, not the shift operation.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I still think that order of operations is the problem here. Consider in decoding that reg(0) takes value from input, and then both reg(0) and input are xor'ed in output. Makes no sense.

Comment: Thats a good and logic idea, thx! You mean like this: http://cife.de/img/snrzi2.gif ? the scrambler outputs then "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0" which can't be right because the idea of the scrambler is to break those long one and zero sequences.

Comment: TempReg(9) should take the value of ShiftReg(9) ^ ShiftReg(8)

Comment: aww you're right, sorry. I updated the initial question post with the code like you suggest. could you please take a look at it? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the decoding part of the code, but in the encoding, there is a big issue: you calculate bits 0 and 9 *after* you perform the shift, which is incorrect. You need to calculate them before you shift your main registers, save them in temp variables (actually it is safe to write #9, but not #0), shift the LFSR, put the calculated bits back in.

What you are doing now is effectively using bits 3 and 7 as tap points, and calculating bit #9 as `bit#7 XOR bit#9` instead of the specified algorithm.

I expect a similar error on the decoding side, but didn't check.

Comment: thanks! i tried to implement your idea, please refer to the code in my question and i also posted new console output which looks better than yesterday but still not like i need.

Comment: I don't see you throwing away the first 9 or 10 bits at decoding. There will be some random data at the output of the decoder until the first bit of input reaches the output. I will check the implementation again to see if I can find anything else.

Comment: On the decoding side, you are updating `bShiftReg[1]` before you shift, which essentially updates `bShiftReg[2]` in addition to the desired cell. Since there are also temps, this can be a copy/paste error, though.

Comment: I do reset the registers at the second for loop in the decoder section. I discovered another error at decoding - calculating the output after `bShiftReg[ 0 ] = *itInput;` makes the statement `*itOutput = ( ( *itInput ^ bShiftReg[0] ) ^ bShiftReg[5] ) ^ bShiftReg[9];` have two equal values in an XOR relation which is incorrect. My current decoder version is this: http://cife.de/img/snrzi3.gif , the decoder outputs " 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0" which is 8 ones too many in comparison to the starting sequence. I tried to move the calculations around but no success.

Comment: What I mean is, since you reset all register bits to 1 at start, it should take 9 or 10 iterations for your first bit of encoded data to reach the decoder output. No matter what you encode, I expect these first bits to be the same, since they don't rely on your encoded data. So you need to throw away some output before recording the decoded output. Actually the same thing happens at the encoder side as well.

Comment: i think i read some other information but thx, i will do some research =)